# Java Jersey-client: witing test a GET method

Tags: java, jersey-client

I want to write a unit test for GET method.I have a GET request that returns a json file of when I request path localhost:9090/application/a/b:

```
 {
     name: a,
     Age:b
 }
```

I want to write unit test using jersey client. I tried writing as such:

```
 Response response = target("a/b").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
```

The objective is to retrieve from the GET response and assert the returned json with an expected value:

```
 assertEqual(expected value:{name: a, Age:b},returned json from response)
```

However, I am not quite sure how I can write this. Can someone guide me on this? I have been searching through many code samples but mostly it is for POST request so I am not sure how this is implemented for GET request.

Edit: I am not required to post anything (I can just grab most code sample for POST) What I am trying to do is just to invoke a call using the path without sending any json document or object and have it returned to me a response in json. After that, I am supposed to grab this json response, and then assert the object with an expected document. The part that I need guidance on is writing the right Response line of code. Also, since my test class has to inherit a jersey client parent, I am expected to use the Response class. I couldnt find any example like this online. That is why I am here to ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add whatever you understood from post samples. what is target() from which class?

Comment: target is a path. At least, that's what I put...

Comment: google something like " rest webservice junit test" , "mocking webservice calls"  etc. you need to learn things

Comment: There is a requirement for me to implement this using jersey client. I tried with mockito way but the code gets overly complicated that I was told to inherit a readily available jersey client class into the test code. If you can narrow down to just jersey client -ish test, that would be a lot better.